# Length of string with \0 in it in C

Tags: c, input, strlen

Well I read input from user as:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", message);
```

And I initialise char message `[100] ="";`  now, in another function I need to find out length of input in message, I did it easily with `strlen()`, unfortunately it doesn't work correctly when I do later in terminal

```
echo -e "he\0llo" | .asciiart 50
```

It will read the whole input BUT `strlen` will only return length 2.

Is there any other way I could find out length of input ?

Comment: `strlen()` searches the char array for the first occurrence of `\0`, so it's impossible to make it to search an arbitrary array populated with `\0` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition *strlen* stops on the null character

you have to count/read up to EOF and/or the newline rather than counting up to the null character after you read the string

As said in a remark `%n` allows to get the number of read characters, example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char message[100] = { 0 };
  int n;

  if (scanf("%99[^\n]%n", message, &n) == 1)
    printf("%d\n", n);
  else
    puts("empty line or EOF");
}
```

Compilations and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "" | ./a.out
empty line or EOF
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo -n "" | ./a.out
empty line or EOF
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo -e "he\0llo" | ./a.out
6
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As you can see it is not possible to distinguish an empty line and EOF (even looking at *errno*)

You can also use `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *lineptr = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  ssize_t sz = getline(&lineptr, &n, stdin);

  printf("%zd\n", sz);

  free(lineptr);
}
```

but the possible newline is get and counted in that case :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -g c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo -e "he\0llo" | ./a.out
7
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo -e -n "he\0llo" | ./a.out
6
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "" | ./a.out
1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo -n "" | ./a.out
-1
```

Comment: @chux you are very right, thank you for the remarks, I edited my answer (I am very surprised I didn't put the limitation to 99 characters, I always set the limitation and say to others to do that ^^)