# How to simplify this readLine() function?

Tags: c, file, text, readline, simplify

I have this function and it reads first line of some .txt file and returns the line for me to work with it. I do NOT know how long is the line going to be so I can not have constant size of buffer. 
My problem is I can not use this function because it would be considered as cheating (I have my exams) because of it is not my code.

I have been thinking about variable length of an array but it is evil as it was said to me and I could just scanf the whole line somewhere I guess but Im not sure how would I do it in this case (I need to return the line)

```c
char* readLine(FILE *line) { 
    char individualChar;
    int pos = 0;
    int size = 16;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(size);

    while ((individualChar = fgetc(line)) != EOF && individualChar != '\n'){
        if (pos + 1 == size){
            size *= 2;
            char *tmp = (char *)realloc(buffer, size);
            if (!tmp){
                free(buffer);
                fprintf(stderr, "Realloc failed");
                return 0;
            }
            buffer = tmp;
        }
        buffer[pos] = individualChar;
        pos++;
    }

    buffer[pos] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Any solution using an array will be limited by the size of the array.

Comment: Instead of calling `fgetc()`, you can call `fgets()` to read in larger chunks. Check the last character of the result to see if it's a newline. If it isn't, reallocate your buffer and call `fgets()` again to get the next chunk. Keep repeating until you get a chunk that ends with newline.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. You don't want to cheat by copying someone else's code, but what else can we answer with?

Comment: Yes, VLAs are evil. Using realloc is the ideal way to do it, but using a fixed array and just documenting the limitation ("This program can only handle lines of text fewer than 4k bytes") is often acceptable.

Comment: Barmar I would like to get some idea how to do it differently. Like "u could use function something() to get this and .... " not sure how to expplain it better.
xing .. and doesnt this int just equals ascii value of the char and it is converted ?

Comment: Whether you use `fgets` or `fgetc` is not likely to make much difference.  The same number of `read` calls will (most likely) be made, as the standard library is well optimized to handle these cases.

Comment: the function: `readline()` is a well known function that prompts the user to input a line of text, then returns a pointer to that line of text to the program.  If you want to use a well known function, suggest using `getline()`

Answer (score 3):

Posting much code here is no good here as OP has

> considered as cheating (I have my exams) because of it is not my code.

So some tips

---

> I do NOT know how long is the line going to be so I can not have constant size of buffer.

Defensive programming assumes a reasonable sane upper bound to prevent hacker exploits.  IAC, reading text files incur *Environmental limits*.

> Environmental limits
>   An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character. The value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256.  C11 §7.21.2 7

With that approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SANE_BOUND (BUFSIZ+1)

char* readLine(FILE *line) { 
  char buffer[SANE_BOUND];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, line) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return strdup(buffer);
}
```

---

> How to simplify this `readLine()` function?

To be clear, the code you do not want to copy has *issues*.

**Corrections**

```
// char is insufficient to distinguish the 257 different results from fgetc()
// char individualChar;
int individualChar;

// Use size_t for sizing, `int` may be too small
size_t pos = 0;
size_t size = 16;
```

Should the first `fgetc()` call return `EOF` or  later call return `EOF` due to a rare input error, the function should return `NULL`.

**Drop the casts, not needed.**

```
//char *buffer = (char *)malloc(size);
//char *tmp = (char *)realloc(buffer, size);
char *buffer = malloc(size);
char *tmp = realloc(buffer, size);
```

**Why incomplete check?**

Code has `if (!tmp){` yet no prior check for `if (!buffer){`

**Minor**

```
// Use \n and stay case correct
// fprintf(stderr, "Realloc failed");
fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed\n");
```

**Pedantic**

`size *= 2;` may overflow.  How safe do you want to be?

**Design**

I'd *right size* with a final `realloc()`.

I'd re-design to convey back to the caller both the size read and the allocated memory.  Text file *lines* uncommonly may contain the *null character* and returning only a *string* pointer does not convey some were read.  Applies to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55207042/2410359) too.

---

A *good* allocating `readLine()` will be less simple than OP's posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simpler approach:

1. count the first line size
2. allocate needed memory in one step
3. read line into allocated memory

This code is not optimal since it reads the file twice, but I think it
will be simpler for you to appropriate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readline(FILE *f)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    char *ret = NULL;
    long pos = ftell(f);

    /* find line size */
    int c = fgetc(f);
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        c = fgetc(f);
        ++size;
    }

    if (size)
    {
        /* allocate mem */
        ret = malloc(size + 1);

        /* rewind file */
        fseek(f, SEEK_SET, pos);

        /* read data */
        fread(ret, 1, size, f);

        /* add string limiter */
        ret[size] = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

**Warning**

This code is incomplete since it does not test:

- for `f` to be not `NULL`
- the return values of `malloc` and `fread`

Comment: wont be there a problem when i read the second line ? I will rewind the whole file not just actual line. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: `rewind()` will be a problem,  Suggest using `fseek()` instead and seeking back, from current position, the length (as used in the call to `malloc()`) to step back to the beginning of the current line

Comment: Not all inputs are seekable, but you should be able to read the line even from non-seekable inputs (such as the terminal!).  Making a human type everything twice just to count how long it is the first time would be unconscionable!  That's a separate problem from the fact that this function is 'readFirstLine()` and not `readLine()`.

Comment: Neither `fprintf()` nor `fscanf()` — nor `fgets()` — checks that the file pointer argument is not null.  That test isn't necessary.  Testing for a null pointer from `malloc()` is necessary.

Comment: "This code is incomplete since it does not test:" --> also no test of `pos != -1` nor `fseek()`.

Comment: Code also does not return a distinguishing result  between end-of-file and reading a `"\n"`.

Comment: @Anders The `fseek(fp, -chars, SEEK_CUR);` and `return chars;` will be off-by-one when `ch == EOF`.

Comment: @chux that;s true